# Como transforma uma função javascript em uma "função" angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache-cordova

Tenho o seguinte codigo Angular.

```
        angular.module("contato", []);
        angular.module("contato").controller("contatoCtrl", function($scope){            
            $scope.app = "contatos";

        });
```

Como usar uma função javascript normal, no formato angular? Por exemplo:

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    console.log('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
```

Transformando ou não em angular, dessa forma:

```
angular.module("contato", []);
            angular.module("contato").controller("contatoCtrl", function($scope){

                $scope.app = "+contato";

                var checkConnection = function () {
                    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
                    var states = {};
                    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
                    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
                    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
                    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
                    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
                    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
                    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
                    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

                    console.log('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
                    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);


                };

                checkConnection();

            });
```

O erro permanece:

```
angular.js:12450 TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at checkConnection (index.html:50)
    at new <anonymous> (index.html:67)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4476)
    at extend.instance (angular.js:9127)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8239)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7671)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:7546)
    at angular.js:1662
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15922)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16022)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12450
```

Comment: não entendi bem sua pergunta... Mas o AngularJs é JS, ou seja, não há nada de errado com a sua função. Se entendi o ponto que você quer chegar, que seria passar os valores para o angular, você pode fazer ao final. Por exemplo: `$scope.states = states;` e toda a propriedade da `var states` será passada para o scope.

Comment: Só complementando o Celsom, como ele disse, AngularJS é Javascript, sem mais. O fato de você ta usando o framework Angular não significa que todas as suas funções, por exemplo, vão estar no $scope. É comum ver muita gente colocando tudo que é função no $scope porque acham que isso é um "padrão" que deve ser seguido pelo framework.

Answer (score 3):

```
$scope.checkConnection = function () {

...
}
```

na sua view voce pode acessar a função, iniciando ao carregar ou clicando num botão, por exemplo:

```
<div init="checkConnection()"></div> //inicia ao carregar a view

<button ng-click="checkConnection()"></button> //inicia com um clique no botão
```